# Meteor dynamic form

Tags: javascript, forms, meteor

i'm creating invoice form in meteorJS. My problem is how to dynamically add next position to my form. In JS(jQuery) it's just append new input after click. But in Meteor I cannot push new fields to template. Anyone know how do it ?

Template:

```
<template name="invForm">
    <form class="newComponent">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Name" />
      <select name="type" class="select2-simple">
        <option value="comp1">Comp1</option>
        <option value="comp2">Comp2</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" class="form-control " name="value0" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Value"/>
      <button type="submit" id="create-new">
        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
      </button>
    </form>
   <button id="addNewValue">Add new value</button>
</template>
```

For example: When I click button - add next input value1, value2, valueX. But no idea how.

```
'click #nextProduct'(event) {
  //push new input to form
}
```

Comment: Read [ask] and create a [mcve]

Comment: @AlonEitan, better ? My problem is: No idea how should i solve my problem in meteorJS. That's why I didn't paste sample of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a dynamic variable that list all the inputs available. 
Here is a quick demo of how you could do it :

First: add a #each loop on your html to repeat the input block as many times as needed

```
<template name="invForm">
    <form class="newComponent">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Name" />
        <select name="type" class="select2-simple">
            <option value="comp1">Comp1</option>
            <option value="comp2">Comp2</option>
        </select>
        {{#each input in inputs}}
            <input type="text" class="form-control " name="{{input.value}}" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Value"/>
        {{/each}}
        <button type="submit" id="create-new">
            <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
        </button>
    </form>
    <button id="addNewValue">Add new value</button>
</template>
```

Second: in your javascript, handle a ReactiveVar and play with it (ie add a new input):

```
Template.invForm.events({
    //Events : type "ev" + tab to create a new event
    'click #addNewValue': function (event, template) {
        var inputs = template.inputs.get();
        inputs.push({value:"newValue"});
        template.inputs.set(inputs);
    },
});

Template.invForm.helpers({
    //helpers : type "hp" + tab to create a new helper
    inputs: function () {
        return Template.instance().inputs.get();
    },
});

Template.invForm.onCreated(function () {
    var self = Template.instance();
    self.inputs = new ReactiveVar({value:"initialValue"})
});
```